# Magento 2.3 | Get a list of all sites

Tags: magento2.3, websites

Is it possible to get a list of all sites programatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can get all  site of Store view using below code:

**You can use below class for getting a list of store view and Magento store running from store view.**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Model;

class StoreList {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $storeRepository;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface  $storeRepository     
   ) {
       $this->storeRepository = $storeRepository;
    }
    public function getAllSiteList()
    {
        $storeviews = $this->storeRepository->getList();
        foreach($storeviews as $store)
        {
            echo $store->getCode();
            echo $store->getName();
            echo $store->getStoreGroupId();
             echo $store->getWebsiteId();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By sites do you mean websites ?

If yes you can use the storeManagerInterface :

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
{
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

And in your function :

```
$this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
```

If you want to retrieve all names or other data you can use a while on it :

```
foreach ($this->storeManager->getWebsites() as $website) {
   echo $website->getName();
}
```